# Maven Gae Jsf2 ExternalizeJavaScript Warning

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, jsf-2

I am using maven, google app engine, jsf2 in one project. However, there happens an exception like below:

```
WARNING: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@dfd2cd: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ExternalizeJavaScript
Haz 13, 2012 8:32:41 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ExternalizeJavaScript
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.addPhaseListeners(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:132)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:204)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:200)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:196)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:239)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:146)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:189)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:128)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:104)

Haz 13, 2012 8:32:41 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
```

I override WebContent.java file however still this problem happens..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ExternalizeJavaScript
>    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.addPhaseListeners(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:132)
> ```

This field was only available in JSF 1.2 and has been removed/deprecated in JSF 2.0. This suggests that you've somewhere a JSF 1.2 implementation JAR file in the runtime classpath. Cleanup the runtime classpath from offending old versioned JAR files.